# IOS: How to print using an IPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, printing

What is the mechanism that allows iPads to print?

I need to print bills from software running on our iPads. The information most likely includes formatter text. Are there any packages for iOS that would allow me to generate reports that can easily be sent to a printer?

Comment: The iPad doesn't have a built-in printer... For anyone to help you need to add more details on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: example: print a sequence of string, is possible?

Comment: In the future questions shouldn't be voted down because one doesnt think an answer exists. Saying that an iPad doesn't have a built-in printer is at best useless and unhelpful. You can print with an iPad since iOS 4.2 to AirPrint capable printers. And a simple program will enable the feature for shared printers on your Mac.

Comment: @Andrew: Agreed on the downvotes, but just because you could guess that he wants to use AirPrint specifically doesn't mean everyone else can nor that he meant that.

Comment: @Georg He didn't know what he didn't know. That was the unfortunate part. It was a simple question. How can I print on an iPad.

Comment: @Andrew: The original question isn't that clear - is it a specific corporate enviroment, or does your interpretation apply? If it does, great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a decent example:
[AirPrint](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-code.html) Tutorial